# How can I pass data with URLs to ui-sref?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I ny view I have: `<a ui-sref="app.file({path: file.path})">{{ file.path }}</a>`

`file.path` is `html/hero-sidebar.html`

My state is defined as:

```
  .state('app.file', {
    url: '/file/*path'
    views:
      repositoryView:
        templateUrl: '/templates/app/_file.html'
  })
```

But when I click the link, it goes to `http://localhost:9001/app/file/html%252Fhero-sidebar.html`

What I want is for it to go to `http://localhost:9001/app/file/html/hero-sidebar.html`

Is this possible using ui-router with AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already logged issue in [**ui-router Github**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), you could found it [**here**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1557#issuecomment-63406753)

In order to solve this you need to add this code inside your config which will take care of encoding and decoding of url.

> you could override the built-in string type (which is performing the
>   slash encoding) by registering your own replacement "string" type using below code

**Code**

```
app.config(['$urlMatcherFactory', '$stateProvider', function($urlMatcherFactory, $stateProvider) {
    //$stateProvider.state() & other code here

    function valToString(val) {
        return val != null ? val.toString() : val;
    }

    function regexpMatches(val) { /*jshint validthis:true */
        return this.pattern.test(val);
    }
    $urlMatcherFactory.type("string", {
        encode: valToString,
        decode: valToString,
        is: regexpMatches,
        pattern: /[^/]*/
    });
}]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TEPEAb?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, it must be the way to go. I've been fiddling with this in a plunk for sometime now, but no joy. Could you please make the plunk work, I've wasted too much time on it already; I've given up on this, but I'm still curious to know what I got wrong: http://plnkr.co/edit/XWndxl?p=preview

Comment: @Manube added the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/XWndxl?p=preview, you made mistake here added `$urlMatcherFactory.type("myType", {` instead of `$urlMatcherFactory.type("string", {`

Comment: Is it working on your side? does it display #/file/html/hero-sidebar.html when you hover the 'html/hero-sidebar.html' link?

Comment: @Manube ya on hover url it is showing the encoded url, but in browser url bar it accurate as we want

Comment: 'myType' was not a mistake, the name can be customised, as explained here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1119#issuecomment-64696060. I'm afraid you forgot to save your work in the plunk, as it is still the same I posted. The plunk was already working in the sense it displayed the view. However, the issue is in the name of the url, which still has %2F or %252F. And I think that when you hover the link, it should display the decoded url. How can you prove it works otherwise?

Comment: @Manube I forgot to save the plunkr, you're right here is updated one http://plnkr.co/edit/TEPEAb?p=preview

Comment: sorry, but the plunk is not working. Proof: change pattern to pattern: /whatever/: the link still displays, still with %2F; in fact, with string it is not using the $urlMatcher; now use url: '/file/{path:myType}' and it uses custom $urlMatcher, but still issues with %2F: http://plnkr.co/edit/veTxYh?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73447/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-manube).