# How to Prevent angular from decoding URIs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a JSON which contains list of link to posts. Some of them are like this:

> %d8%b3%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%85-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7

I using ui-route and creating links this way:

```
<a ui-sref="post({ id: post.ID, title: post.slug })" class="post-list-title"></a>
```

But the result are looks like this:

> %25d8%25b3%25d9%2584%25d8%25a7%25d9%2585-%25d8%25af%25d9%2586%25db%258c%25d8%25a7

Angular converted % to %25 and this is not what I need. So How to prevent converting % to %25 ?

Comment: looks something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29169510/2435473

Comment: I found new way to solve this, but last night i was too sleepy to write more :d . BTW the following comment is my solution.

Comment: vm.getSlug = function(post) {
        return decodeURIComponent(post.slug);
    };